# Convergence in distribution and in moment... and in central moments?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

In Fumio Hayashi's [Econometrics](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/6946.html), Lemma 2.1 (convergence in distribution and in moments) states that

> **Lemma 2.1** $\quad$ Let $\alpha_{sn}$ be the $s$-th moment of $z_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_{sn}=\alpha_s$ where $\alpha_s$ is finite. Then $$ z_n \to_d z \implies \alpha_s \text{ is the $s$-th moment of $z$}$$

Then the author goes on to comment that

> For example, if the variance of a sequence of random variables converging in distribution converges to some finite number, then that number is the variance of the limiting distribution.

My question is, **Why is this comment true?** I don't think this lemma about moments can be directly applied to the variance, which is a *central* moment. If this is not a direct application, it remains unclear to me how this lemma can lead to the author's claim about the variance.

Call the sequence of our concern $y_n\to_d y$. To apply the lemma to the variance, we need to convert $y_n$ into $z_n:=y_n-\mathbb{E}[y_n]$, so that the convergence $\operatorname{Var}[y_n]\to\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is translated into $\mathbb{E}[(z_n)^2] \to \alpha$. The obstacle to apply the lemma is, we do not know $z_n:=y_n-\mathbb{E}[y_n]$ converges in distribution to $y-\mathbb{E}[y]$ or not (for one thing, $\{\mathbb{E}[y_n]\}$ is not known to converge). If this were known, then by the lemma $\mathbb{E}[(y-\mathbb{E}[y])^2]=\alpha$, as desired.

Comment: If the second moment converges and the first moment converges then the variance converges, since the variance is $E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ and $x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous. The same is true of higher central moments, which are polynomial functions of the lower moments.

Comment: @Ian Yes! But I guess Hayashi's comment isn't made on the assumption that the first moment converges?

Comment: I'm not following. Apply the lemma with $s=1$ and then again with $s=2$ and conclude. What's wrong with that?

Comment: With no further hypothesis than what you wrote in the question, Lemma 2.1 seems spectacularly wrong: consider $z_n$ such that $P(z_n=n)=1-P(z_n=0)=1/n$ then $\alpha_{1n}=1\to\alpha_1=1$ but $z_n\to z=0$ in distribution and $\alpha_1=1$ is not the first moment of the random variable $z=0$.

Comment: @Ian Why can you apply the lemma though? How do you know, for example, that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[z_n]=\alpha_1$, where $\alpha_1$ is finite? The only condition we can use in Hayashi's comment is "the variance of a sequence of random variables converging in distribution converges to some finite number." I understand that to mean only $z_n \to_d z$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{Var}(z_n)\to V$ where $V\in\mathbb{R}$. I don't see how do they imply $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[z_n]=\alpha_1,$ which applying the lemma in the case of $s=1$, as you suggest, requires.

Comment: @Did I'm afraid what you said is correct... I just checked the book again and I don't think I missed any additional assumptions. Hayashi does provide a proof to this lemma, but mentions one can be found in Rao (1973, Chapter 2c) (the title of the reference is *Linear Statistical Inference and Its Applications* (2/e)). I will see if I can find this original source.

Comment: Another assertion which is completely wrong is that "the variance of a sequence of random variables converging in distribution converges to some finite number."

Comment: Actually H gives no source for their Lemma 2.1 (the reference to Rao stands for the result just before Lemma 2.1). Just after the (wrong) Lemma 2.1, H states the (wrong) consequence that if the variances of a sequence of random variables converging in distribution converge to some finite number $L$ then $L$ is the variance of the limiting distribution. Counterexample: $P(z_n=+\sqrt{n})=P(z_n=-\sqrt{n})=\frac1{2n}$, $P(z_n=0)=1-\frac1n$, then $L=1$ but $z_n\to0$ in distribution. // Yet another author to whom a quick fact-checking of their book by some mathematician would have been useful...

Comment: The faulty statement of Lemma 2.1 is acknowledged by the author in this list of typos: http://fhayashi.fc2web.com/hayashi%20econometrics/typos.pdf

Comment: @Did Thank you so much! I didn't know there was such an errata. This should be helpful. If you'd like to put together your comments and counterexamples into an answer, I'd accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Better if you post all thi as an answer yourself, and even, after a while, accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments to the question, both Lemma 2.1 and Hayashi's comment are incorrect. The issue with the Lemma is in [Hayashi's errata.](http://fhayashi.fc2web.com/hayashi%20econometrics/typos.pdf)

Counterexample to Lemma 2.1:
Let $z_n$ be such that $\mathbb{P}\{z_n=n\} = \frac{1}{n}$ and $\mathbb{P}\{z_n=0\} = \frac{n-1}{n}$. Then $\mathbb{E}[z_n] = 1$. $z_n \to_d 0 =: z$. Clearly, $1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[z_n] \ne \mathbb{E}[z]=0.$

Counterexample to Hayashi's comment:
Let $z_n$ be such that $\mathbb{P}\{z_n = \sqrt{n}\} = \mathbb{P}\{z_n = -\sqrt{n}\} = \frac{1}{2n}$ and $\mathbb{P}\{z_n = 0\} = 1-\frac{1}{n}.$ Then $\operatorname{Var}(z_n) = 1 \to 1$ as $n\to\infty.$ However, $z_n\to_d 0 =: z,$ so $\operatorname{Var}(z) = 0 \ne 1.$